# Set cookie in js, can't read in golang

Tags: javascript, go, cookies

i set 2 cookie, 1 from golang, 1 from js like this

**Golang**

```
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("mysession"))
session, _ := store.Get(request, "mysession")
session.Values["usename"] = username
session.Values["status"] = status
err = session.Save(request, response)
if err != nil {
http.Error(response, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}
```

**js**

```
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    time += 3600 * 1000;
    now.setTime(time);
json_str = JSON.stringify(json_data).toString();
document.cookie = 
    'mycode=' + json_str + 
    '; expires=' + now.toUTCString() + 
    '; path=/';
```

the cookie is displayed when i print Request:

Cookie:[mysession=MTU4ODE0MjQ1NXxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUkFCRUFBQVBmLUNBQUlHYzNSeWFXNW5EQWdBQm5OMFlYUjFjd05wYm5RRUFnQUNCbk4wY21sdVp3d0pBQWQxYzJWdVlXMWxCbk4wY21sdVp3d0ZBQU5oYzJRPXxusqTQsJ68z5ZYx13pDMI1vZWVu0pI_zvWh267DQkRYA==; **mycode=**[["200412133557",11,"6"]]] Referer:[http://localhost:3000/index]

that show me 2 cookie, but when i want to get cookie with golang:

```
func Keranjang(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    cookie1, err := request.Cookie("mysession")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cant find cookie mysession ")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("mysession found ")
        fmt.Println(cookie1)
    }

    cookie2, err := request.Cookie("mycode")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cant find cookie mycode ")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("mycode found ")
        fmt.Println(cookie2)
    }

}
```

Output:

mysession found mysession=MTU4ODE0MjQ1NXxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUkFCRUFBQVBmLUNBQUlHYzNSeWFXNW5EQWdBQm5OMFlYUjFjd05wYm5RRUFnQUNCbk4wY21sdVp3d0pBQWQxYzJWdVlXMWxCbk4wY21sdVp3d0ZBQU5oYzJRPXxusqTQsJ68z5ZYx13pDMI1vZWVu0pI_zvWh267DQkRYA==
Cant find cookie mycode

why my second cookie is not found?

i have many try

*** try1: 
`cookie2, err := request.Cookie(" mycode")`

`cookie2, err := request.Cookie("mycode=")` and same result, am i mistype or something?

*** try2: with session get

```
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("mycode"))
cookie2, err := store.Get(request, "mycode")
```

and cookie 'mycode' is found, the output is map: 
&{ map[] 0xc000038100 true 0xc000096e80 mycode}
but the value **["200412133557",11,"6"]** is missing in map?

*** try3: i create one more cookie in golang

```
c.Name = "kuki"
c.Expires = time.Now().Add(5 * time.Minute)
http.SetCookie(response, c)
```

i print all cookie with `fmt.Println(request.Cookies())`
output:

[mysession=MTU4ODE0MjQ1NXxEdi1CQkFFQ180SUFBUkFCRUFBQVBmLUNBQUlHYzNSeWFXNW5EQWdBQm5OMFlYUjFjd05wYm5RRUFnQUNCbk4wY21sdVp3d0pBQWQxYzJWdVlXMWxCbk4wY21sdVp3d0ZBQU5oYzJRPXxusqTQsJ68z5ZYx13pDMI1vZWVu0pI_zvWh267DQkRYA== **kuki=**]

cookie 'mycode' created by js still not readable,
Are there different types of JS and Golang cookies?

Comment: Isn't the problem the fact that you're setting the cookie's expires value to *now*, assuming now is not sometime in the future that cookie would be expired right after declaration, no?

Comment: i have set date now before, ```var now = new Date();
  var time = now.getTime();
  time += 3600 * 1000;
  now.setTime(time);```

and i try this code in golang
```cookie2, err := store.Get(request, "mycode")```

and it found but output is 

found &{ map[] 0xc000038100 true 0xc000096e80 mycode}

but mycode value is missing []

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figure it out,
HTTP Cookie in golang doesn't support  "  double quoted value.
So based on advice, i parse js cookie value to base64 `window.btoa(json_str)` , passing through cookie and decode in golang `decoded, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cookie2.Value)`